# Looking for the checksum for Ubuntu 14.0.4.3 32-bit

Tags: checksums

When I started the download for 14.0.4.3 32-bit I didn't find any obvious link to a list of checksums. I'd suggest that site management add that information. in the meantime can someone point me to the appropriate checksum please!

Answer (score 0):

Checksums are included [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/).

```
cab6dd5ee6d649ed1b24e807c877c0ae *ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
0bc058cdc75fb75d4922c7c74c4cd6b1 *ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386.iso
9e5fecc94b3925bededed0fdca1bd417 *ubuntu-14.04.3-server-amd64.iso
352009d5b44f0e97c9558919f0147c0c *ubuntu-14.04.3-server-i386.iso
b31731ea6cdbebe1d02f8193db420886 *wubi.exe
```

**Source** : http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/MD5SUMS